# VSTO Excel Application with multi-level review - looking for alternate for embedded tickmarks

Tags: excel, vsto, workflow

I have a fairly old VSTO Excel application that requires multiple levels of review of data in the  cells. Currently, reviewed cells are identified by embedded image (tick mark). So, if two levels of review is done then there are two tick marks. If the reivewed cell is modified then the tick marks turn red. The issue is the embedded tickmarks make the file large and slow to open. Are there better ways to handle this multi-level review visually.

[image: Excel with tick mark image in cell]